# How do I access Apache error logs via the Terminal in Mac OS X 10.6.8?

Tags: macos, ruby-on-rails-3.1, apache2

I am having trouble with serving up my rails app on a remote computer after upgrading from Rails 3.0 to 3.1. So I want to take a look at what exactly is going wrong when Apache attempts to start up my app and it fails. How can I find the errors that Apache (or maybe Passenger?) is throwing via the Terminal?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

in terminal, have you tried

```
cat /var/log/apache2/error_log
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I saw that this path for the location of the error log is in the httpd.conf file--just in case this isn't the path for everyone.

Comment: If you just want to look at the last few lines of the log use `tail /var/log/apache2/error_log` instead. The error log tends to get bigger/longer with time.

Answer (score 2):

only to complemente the others answers, I'm using the version 10.9.3 and to me, the address is:

```
/private/var/log/apache2
```

Comment: On OSX `/var`, `/etc`, and `/tmp` are symlinked to `/private/var`, `/private/etc`, and `/private/tmp`.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

cat /private/var/log/apache2/error_log